# HaoIDE: Component is not active (Run Test Class)

Tags: unit-test, sublime, haoide

Using the [HaoIDE](https://github.com/xjsender/haoide) add-on for [SublimeText 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) I'm having an issue when I attempt to "**Run Test Class**" from the context menu, it seems to be greyed out and when I use the hot key (`Ctrl+Alt+T`) I see an error message at the bottom that says "Component is not active"

I the correct project active and the class I have open is in fact a `@isTest` class that is already deployed to the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is likely an issue with the session of your project to environment. Try some of the following options (preferably in this order):

- Restart Sublime Text (there may be an update that needs to happen from HaoIDE)
- HaoIDE > Cache > Clear Session Cache (this should end your session so you can refresh it)
- HaoIDE > Switch Project (This should re-attempt to login to the projects SF environment with a new session)
- HaoIDE > Update Project (This should re-sync your project)

> **NOTE: File vs Project Context/Relationship**

Also keep in mind that all context menu options from HaoIDE are related to the project and file relationship. So for example, if I have Production AND Sandbox packages locally that I'm working in, and I have a ***production*** file open but I'm in the ***sandbox*** project, then there is no relationship and the typical options like "*Run Test Class*" **will not be available**